# get window handler from started process

Tags: python, pywin32

I see there's `win32process.GetWindowThreadProcess()` that gets a window handler and returns it's process id. Is there a way to do the opposite: get the window handler of a running process by it's process id? Something like `win32gui.GetWindowHandler(processId)` ?

**Specifically What I'm trying to do:**

I have a python script that runs an external program, lets say notepad.exe. 
Notepad is fired when `runProgram()` method is called. I want to prevent this method from running Notepad **more than once.** I accomplish this in the following way, using [win32process](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.4/pywin32/win32process.html):

```
import win32process as process
import sys

PORTABLE_APPLICATION_LOCATION = "C:\\Windows\\system32\\notepad.exe"
processHandler = -1

def runProgram():
    global processHandler
    #don't run a process more than once
    if (isLiveProcess(processHandler)):
        #Bring focus back to running window!
        return;
    try:
        startObj = process.STARTUPINFO()
        myProcessTuple = process.CreateProcess(PORTABLE_APPLICATION_LOCATION,None,None,None,8,8,None,None,startObj)
        processHandler = myProcessTuple[2]
    except:
        print(sys.exc_info[0])

def isLiveProcess(processHandler): #Process handler is dwProcessId
    processList = process.EnumProcesses()
    for aProcess in processList:
        if (aProcess == processHandler):
            return True
    return False

runProgram()
```

This works as expected, but if the process is found to be already alive, I'd like to bring it's window back to front with [win32gui](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.4/pywin32/win32gui.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I dont think that Windows API provides a method for this , but you could iterate over all open windows , and find the one that belongs to you .

I have modified your program so it looks like this :

```
import win32process
import win32process as process
import win32gui
import sys

PORTABLE_APPLICATION_LOCATION = "C:\\Windows\\system32\\notepad.exe"
processHandler = -1


def callback(hwnd, procid):
    if procid in  win32process.GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd):
        win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(hwnd)

def show_window_by_process(procid):
    win32gui.EnumWindows(callback, procid)


def runProgram():
    global processHandler
    #don't run a process more than once
    if (isLiveProcess(processHandler)):
        #Bring focus back to running window!
        show_window_by_process(processHandler)
        return;
    try:
        startObj = process.STARTUPINFO()
        myProcessTuple = process.CreateProcess(PORTABLE_APPLICATION_LOCATION,None,None,None,8,8,None,None,startObj)
        processHandler = myProcessTuple[2]
    except:
        print(sys.exc_info[0])

def isLiveProcess(processHandler): #Process handler is dwProcessId
    processList = process.EnumProcesses()
    for aProcess in processList:
        if (aProcess == processHandler):
            return True
    return False

 runProgram()
```

Comment: Yes, I saw this option in my research. This is problematic because a title of an app may vary: opening a file for example may change the title of the notepad from `Notepad.exe` to `fileName.txt`. I'm thinking of implementing this with processId instead of title, Just thought maybe there is something which is more straight forward.

Comment: Cheers, with this edit it's exactly how it's done. A little side note: My testings results show that `win32gui.ShowWindow(hwnd,1)` has a better effect than `SetForegroundWindow(hwnd)` and seems to work better.